# Cannot Load Record Page Using iFrame In LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, iframe, lightning-record-page

I've tried many ways to load a record page using iFrame but it just return a white empty screen.

When I tried to load it with example from [Techdicer](https://techdicer.com/use-iframe-in-lwc-salesforce/#:%7E:text=We%20use%20the%20iframe%20to,page%20can%20load%20in%20Salesforce.) , it worked. Then I just replaced the url in src attribute with my Salesforce record page `https://example-ed.develop.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Account/0062t000007xxxxxx/view`

Html Code

```
<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 100%"
        src={url}
        scrolling="auto"
        referrerpolicy={referrerPolicy}
        sandbox={sandbox}
        title="Record Page">
</iframe>
```

LWC Code

```
@track referrerPolicy = 'no-referrer';
@track sandbox = '';
@track url = 'https://example-ed.develop.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Account/0062t000007xxxxxx/view';
```

Thank you

Comment: If you are simply trying to present a record, could you not just embed a `lightning-record-form` component in your LWC?

Comment: Hi @PhilW, I would like to display an entire page including the Highlight Panel + Detail Page, etc. Using `lightning-record-form` can only display record details.

Comment: Won't you also get the header, with global search, app launcher and navigation bar? That'll be a mess...

Comment: You can use components to show the "highlight panel" and "detail" plus "related lists" if you need all of these. Way better than trying to iframe it in.

Comment: Thank you, I'll consider your recommendation. Meanwhile, I hope I'll have the answer the iFrame to know if Salesforce supports it or not.

Comment: your url does not go to a valid website? why is there xxxxx in your recordId?

Comment: Hi @prem22 , I changed it because of privacy matter. I'm sure I use the right url in my real code.

Comment: Have you checked for CORS errors or warnings in your browser console? Have you reviewed debug logs? (Use of iframe is highly problematic and not recommended at all in general terms, and Salesforce are quite cautious about allowing their use without trusted sites, for example.)

Comment: Hi @PhilW, thank you for your comments.

I've done a couple research after this question and found out that embedded a Salesforce using Ifram is not allowed. Salesforce prevents this action.

Comment: @Pam you should ensure you provide a self-answer to close this question off. I hope the suggestion of adding [`lightning-record-form`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation) with both `Compact` and `Full` `layout-type` variants and the related lists via `lightning-datatable` populated from the [`ui-related-list-api`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-ui-related-list-api/documentation) data helps you out.

Comment: Note that the `lightning-record-form` is restricted to using page layouts at the moment; it doesn't support dynamic forms (yet?).

Comment: Thank you so much @PhilW, I provided an answer and closed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce does not allow using Iframe to embed a Salesforce record link due to security restrictions and limitations imposed.

Salesforce enforces strict security measures to protect its platform and customer data. One of these measures is the Content Security Policy (CSP), which restricts the types of content that can be loaded within a Salesforce page.

=> There is no solution for this question.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lightning_out